# software that support apple's http live streaming

Tags: http-live-streaming

Is there any client or player on PC or linux platform which supports Apple http live streaming draft propsal. That is, it is able to reload the m3u8 playlist automatically to do live streaming. I tried [apple's sample page](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbopall.html) for iphone on Safari and Chrome, not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that VLC can do the trick
(http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.0.2.html)
I quote: "Support for new adaptive streaming protocols, like HLS and DASH."